# Magento Mass User Email

Tags: php, magento

I want to send an email to all my customers which will include their password. I tried to first subscribe everyone to the newsletter in the backend, but if I do that a subscription confirmation letter is send. How can I stop that confirmation email from firing, and how to include their login info on a newsletter template?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might have better luck over at http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Mass email is extension which allow admin to select multiple users from grid and send them email together.This mass email extension provides you wysiwyg editor for your email content.You can add anything to your email body.
This extension also provides place holders like [customer.firstname],[customer.lastname], [customer.email] which will replace with registred user name email etc when email is sent.This extension is very useful for email marketing your magento products and new added products alerts to customers.

Extension:http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mass-email-to-registered-customers-7187.html

Reference Url:
https://www.behance.net/gallery/5247629/Magento-Mass-Email-Extension

Comment: Can it handle sending email to all customers? 500-600